# function with two variables: one will be used as a string into the function - Python 3 - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, variables

I am now writing a few functions when using Pandas.
My question should be simple for you:
I want to create a function that receives two variables, one needs to be reused into the function but as a string (Cf. Code - variable value need to be reusend in contains)

```
def delete_lines_that_contains_certain_value(dataframe, value):
    dataframe = dataframe[~dataframe.index.str.contains(str(value), na=False)]
    return dataframe
```

Please could you tell me how to figure out with it in order to make value read as a string when using contains fct from pandas?

when running the function like that, I received an error:

```
delete_line_that_contains_certain_value(test, female)

OUPUT:
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-f2718fe5c59a> in <module>
----> 1 delete_line_that_contains_certain_value(test, female)

NameError: name 'female' is not defined
```

Wait for answers. Thanks

Comment: put quotes around female ... ```'female'```

Comment: it does not work i received an error issue : AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: I would like alos the function to take care of the conversion to string...

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: share a sample of ur dataset, so the function can be tested on

Comment: the dataframe is quite big - how can I copy a dataframe in this window?

Comment: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61195582/function-with-two-variables-one-will-be-used-as-a-string-into-the-function-py/61196545?noredirect=1#comment108260886_61196545)  `code` sex seniority age of student educational stream school type job teaching profession Q_1